# Best Method for creating A Menu in SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Assuming you were coding a menu for a videogame with the average three buttons, a start game button, an options button and an extras button, in c++ with SDL2, what would be the most efficient, clean or functional way to go about this?

Comment: This is a huge question. SDL doesn't provide any means for creating a menu directly, it just offers rendering and event handling. To get some ideas it may be worth having a look at http://members.chello.nl/w.boeke/SDL-widgets/ which is a UI toolkit built on top of SDL.

Comment: @Colin__s I meant like say, if button1 is currently selected and user presses a key down change button to button2.

Comment: You need to make your widgets system, I've implemented one in my SDL2 wrapper, you can take a look and inspire yourself : https://github.com/jordsti/stigame/tree/master/StiGame/gui